# At what point is it sensible to move a join based query from NoSQL to SQL

Tags: sql, azure, nosql

I've a NoSQL table (Azure Table Storage) that holds video metadata and a URL to the stream. Where the partition key is the video ID and row key defines the version of that video. Simplified version:

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|    Partition Key    |      Row Key     |        Stream       |       Hits       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|    1500-8551-15     |         1        |     https://...     |        56        |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

> A new requirement asks to store the user that has viewed a video and
>   how many times that user has watched it.

**Solution 1**

If we continued with a NoSQL solution we could create a new column that holds all the unique user IDs as JSON (or similar) - easy enough to parse. Unfortunately we are then unable to track which user has seen a video multiple times nicely.

**Solution 2**

We could then move to having a second table to hold the user's unique id, which videos they have watched and how many times. The partition key is based on the video ID and the row key is the user ID

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|    Partition Key    |      Row Key     |        Views        | 
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|    1500-8551-15     |     15085511     |          3          |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
```

A query is easy enough to write based on the video key and if we have a specific user we want to query.

This new requirement might be the beginning of an analytics feature. For instance, in the future we may want to know what videos a specific user has watched - via a table scan when using Solution 2. The dataset will be small enough for awhile still for this to not be much of a performance hit. *Famous last words.*

Here, our current setup doesn't need any complex SQL features and NoSQL is cheaper for us. If in the future we need to write some simple queries, NoSQL might still work - but it won't with complex ones that we *might* have to write.

At what point is it sensible to move over to a relational database, as a couple of simpler queries are fine across non-relational, but roughly what is the tipping point?

This isn't a question on the pros and cons of each type of data storage, it's trying to focus on the grey area where both can do the job and when to jump ship from one to the other.

Comment: There's really no right answer to this, other than "it depends." :) And NoSQL vs Relational... just remember that NoSQL isn't a type of database. It's just an umbrella term loosely representing non-relational databases. You need to think about your query needs, your fixed-vs-variable storage needs, etc.

Comment: Also: You've made an assumption that you need to shift from key/value store to a relational store to do proper queries, which isn't necessarily needed. You also have column, document, and graph to consider. Lots of great stuff to choose from.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Yeah quite right. Though we're heavily a Microsoft house here, but I have tried to keep it broad in order to get more view points like you've brought up that we've missed.

Comment: What was the reasoning for NoSQL in the first place? That might inform us as to how/when relational becomes practical

Answer (score 0):

There is no definitive answer for that, but here are my thoughts on the subject:

A - Solution 1 is vary bad, it won't let you track the users, it will required a JSON update (getting the JSON, update it and saving it) each time a user watched a video and, moreover, the value of this column can become very big very fast.

B - Solution 2 can work, but if you would like the ability to see which movie a user watched I would advice to add a second/reversed table where the partition-key is the userId and the row-key is the movieId. That of course will required two updates each time a user watched a movie but you will avoid the table-scan which is a bad practice that will have performance degradation liner to the data size.

C - SQL doesn't necessarily will provide a better performance or will have any additional values. Unless you will have to do complex joins or full data scan (when you don't have the userId or movieId), something like "Find all users which watched 5 or more movies" or "Find pair of users which both watched the same movie", etc.

So it is really an architecture question that only by fully understanding the use cases you are expecting can be answered.

I hope this help (: